# How to evaluate this statement?

Tags: c++

If I defined the absolute value of a number as

```
#define ABS(X) X >= 0 ? X : (-1) * X
```

what would

```
ABS(2) + ABS(-3)
```

evaluate to?  My friend claims it evaluates to 2.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Well I also wanted to know why.

Comment: `2 >= 0 ? 2 : (-1) * 2 + -3 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3`

Comment: a demonstration of why you should not use #define macros - use inline functions instead

Comment: And what we learn from this example: you should always put parentheses around the result of a `#define` intended to be used as an expression: `#define ABS(X) (X >= 0 ? X : (-1) * X)`

Comment: @aschepler More parens required: `#define ABS(X) ((X) >= 0 ? (X) : (-1) * (X))` (for the case of `ABS(i + 1)`).

Comment: @michaelb958: Good point; that's the counterpart rule to this one, and they ought to be learned and remembered together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type:

```
ABS(2) + ABS(-3)
```

This will substitute out to:

```
2 >= 0 ? 2 : (-1) * 2 + -3 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3
```

You can break this down:

```
2 >= 0 ? 2 : -5 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3
```

Or:

```
2 >= 0 ? 2 : (-5 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3)
```

The first part (`2 >= 0`) evaluates as true, so it evaluates to `2`.

Note that you could easily solve this by writing the macro as:

```
#define ABS(X) ((X) >= 0 ? (X) : (-1) * (X))
```

This will keep the evaluation order as expected, and cause it to resolve to 5 instead of 2.  That being said, using an inline function would be much cleaner, and avoid this entire scenario.

Comment: Your fix to the macro, by wrapping it in parens, won't work for all cases.  Consider `ABS( t>=0? -1 : 1)`.  That won't expand as a human would anticipate.  For macros, typically wrap the parameters in parens, AND wrap the entire macro:   `#define ABS(X) ((X)>=0 ? (X) : (-1)*(X))`   (Even this doesn't handle all cases, especially where X has side-effects.  But it does fairly well)

Comment: @abelenky True - wrapped internal `X` in parentheses to try to handle this in my answer.  Good point.

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor performs text-based (actually, token-based) substitution. It does not pay any attention to logical expression grouping.

Given

```
#define ABS(X) X >= 0 ? X : (-1) * X

ABS(2)
```

expands to

```
2 >= 0 ? 2 : (-1) * 2
```

and

```
ABS(-3)
```

expands to

```
-3 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3
```

so

```
ABS(2) + ABS(-3)
```

expands to

```
2 >= 0 ? 2 : (-1) * 2 + -3 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3
```

Now look how the operators are grouped, and you will see why the intuitive answer of 5 is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I read it:

```
ABS(2) + ABS(-3)
```

becomes:

```
2 >= 0 ? 2 : (-1) * 2 + -3 >= 0 ? -3 : (-1) * -3
```

Adding some parens for clarification:

```
(2 >= 0) ? 2 : (((-1) * 2 + -3 >= 0) ? -3 : (-1) * -3)
```

And evaluating:
2 is in fact >= 0, therefore: **2**
(and everything else, starting with `(((-1`, is ignored)

So, I agree with your friend.

Comment: This is the C preprocessor; you *can't* assume parens that aren't there. CPP performs pure text substitution.

Comment: I made NO assumptions about parens.  I placed them according to normal order of operations, only to aid in human-understanding.  If I placed them properly, they don't change the computer-interpretation at all.

Comment: That'll teach me to blindly misinterpret stuff... I just assumed you were rushing in and reparenthesising to force the "correct" result of 5. Sorry.